# Google Sheets cant get data from Twitch Clips using ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, twitch

So I've been trying to fetch the name of the title of Twitch Clips and insert it into a cell on Google Sheets.

On this example below (link to clip: https://clips.twitch.tv/OnerousProtectiveArugulaMVGame-GGYT4CwrktmdYJaC ) I want to fetch the title which is "Nmplol from the future sniping Botez sisters".

On the right you can see the name of the class is  `sc-AxgMl iHVMfi` that corresponds to the title of any Twitch Clip.

[image: Twitch clip preview + Inspect Element on the right showing the class name]

I've tried this expression  `=IMPORTXML("https://clips.twitch.tv/OnerousProtectiveArugulaMVGame-GGYT4CwrktmdYJaC"; "//span[@class='sc-AxgMl iHVMfi']")`  but it keeps telling me "#N/A
Error Imported content is empty".

I've also tried copying the XPath (which is: `//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/span` on the 2nd field of IMPORTXML but it keeps telling me the same.

I've tried using 'SelectorGadget' Chrome extension to get another XPath ( which is `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "iHVMfi", " " ))]` when clicking above the title and then copying into the 2nd field of IMPORTXML but it also keeps telling me the same error.

Any help on this would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. in your case, that's nothing, unfortunately:

[image]